# How to add a button in Akeneo that is going to display certain content?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7, akeneo

I am a beginner in using Akeneo, but I know how to follow up a documentation. 
https://docs.akeneo.com/cookbook/ui_customization/add_a_custom_button_to_product_edit_form.html

I tried this, and it worked, but I want to add a new button which is going to display same attribute group as it already has inside the same product.

Comment: display same attribute group as it already has inside the same product ? can you be more clear?